# SERVER ERROR (wp-admin urls won't load, site will)

Tags: 500-internal-error

**Server error**

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mydomain.org/wp-admin/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Here are some suggestions:

Reload this webpage later.

*HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.*

I just restored my site from backup using BackUp Buddy and `importbuddy.php` file. The site works, all the pages are there, but... the wp-admin doesn't load. I'm confused as to what would cause this.

**UPDATE:** It seems that any url with wp-admin in it is giving me the same error.

Comment: do you have extra non-default rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: http://codepad.org/43t9YNQQ

Comment: this is a multisite install then?

Comment: You will have to look in server logs or ask hosting support to. Error 500 is very generic and it's hard to guess what the issue is for it.

Comment: This is multisite.